# Which projection is best when implementing regional datasets in a global one?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, global

I have a question regarding the projection. I would like to set up an interactive atlas where the base layer is a global overview of e.g. peatland. In a next step, I would like to set into the global overview point layers which enables to zoom in and to have a look on a regional map of peatland. For the global layer, I would like to use WGS84; for the regional maps I would like to avoid using several different projections, i.e. I would like to use max 2 different projections for regional maps worldwide.

Do you have suggestions which projections are best for the above-mentioned purpose?

Comment: 2 seems an arbitrary number why not 3 or 4?

Comment: My idea was to use one for the southern and one for the northern hemisphere. Do you have another suggestion? thank you!

Comment: "Best" questions are problematic in GIS SE, because they are generally discussion-oriented and too *opinion-based* to be of general long-term value. While, in theory, this would be on-topic in [Chat], there is a minimum reputation requirement, and, frankly, almost no participation. If you want to solicit opinions, I suggest a different forum.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.